# nx monorepo: show stack traces in cypress runner

Tags: cypress, nrwl

I am using

- "@nrwl/angular": "11.1.1"
- "@nrwl/cypress": "11.1.1"
- "cypress": "6.2.1"

I would like to see the stack traces in the cypress runner as described here:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Source-maps

I added `"inlineSourceMap": true` tu the `tsconfig` in the e2e directory, but the stack trace is not shown as in the screenshot in the linked documentation.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: What command are you using to run your tests, and what script command does this correlate to in your package.json file?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! I usually run nx e2e --watch from the terminal and then I run the tests from inside the cypress runner